# JSON serialization DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior

Tags: c#, json, wcf, dictionary, serialization

I have a WCF web application (.NET Frameword 4.6.2) which have the following endpoint :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Products/{id}")]
public ProductDTO GetProduct(string id)
{ 
   return Services.GetProduct(id);
}
```

My DTO has some properties like Name, Price and also a Dictionary of custom properties.

```
[DataContract­]
[Serializable]
public class ProductDTO 
{
   [DataMember(Name = "Props", IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
   public IDictionary<string, string> Props {get;set;}
}
```

I use the default Json serializer from .net to send the response to the client side and the dictionary property is serialized that way :

```
{
 "Key":"propKey",
 "Value":"propValue"
}
```

I would like it to be without the keywords "key" and "value". I know we can use  `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` to change this setting which is `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat`. My problem is how can I change this settings for the default framework behaviors for this operation or all my operation contracts? I know I could use Json.Net to fix this use issue, but on short term I'd like to stick with `DataContractJsonSerializer`. Is there a way I can override a behavior so I can set this setting?

I tried to override the following behavior but it didn't work.

```
public class DataContractJsonSerializerOperationBehavior : DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
{
    public DataContractJsonSerializerOperationBehavior(OperationDescription operation) : base(operation) {}

    public DataContractJsonSerializerOperationBehavior(OperationDescription operation, DataContractFormatAttribute dataContractFormatAttribute) : base(operation, dataContractFormatAttribute) {}

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(System.Type type, string name, string ns, IList<System.Type> knownTypes)
    {
        /* Never called */
    }

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(System.Type type, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns, IList<System.Type> knownTypes)
    {
        /* Never called */
    }
}
```

And I also set the behavior for my endpoint:

```
        foreach (OperationDescription operationDescription in serviceEndpoint.Contract.Operations)
        {
            DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dataContractBehavior = operationDescription.Behaviors[typeof(DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior)] as DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior;
            if (dataContractBehavior != null)
            {
                operationDescription.Behaviors.Remove(dataContractBehavior);
                operationDescription.Behaviors.Add(new DataContractJsonSerializerOperationBehavior(operationDescription));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending too much time on this, I ended up changing the default serializer from DataContractSerializer to JSON.Net ... I don't think it's even possible to change the setting I was looking for with DataContractSerializer as default serializer.

Answer (score 0):

It worth looking on 
`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings`
Maybe it help